# Parallel tasks stop working on Spring Boot 3.2 and Java 21

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, java-21

Just migrate my application to Spring boot 3.2 and Java 21. On the start , it loads data from MongoDB in parallel threads, main thread waits till all loads finished, and then take it to internal cache. Have few collections -> so exact number of DataLoader classes.
Before updating it works with ExecutorService without any problems:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(dataLoaders.size());
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (DataLoader dataLoader : dataLoaders) {
    futures.add(executorService.submit(dataLoader::load));
}
try {
    for (Future<?> future : futures) {
    future.get();            }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Can not initialize", e);
}
```

each load() method gets data by slices from MongoRepositories for each collection. Now this all tasks start at different threads and they are all blocked and not completed. Waiting time - infinity. What can be a reason?

Tried to use CompletableFuture, checked all versions of all dependencies at Spring Boot 3.2.0, checked mongoDb Driver, debugged. Expect that all parallel tasks will complete and application will start

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of deadlock of pool threads and main thread. One of solutions - launch dataLoaders after all beans are initialized. Current class must implement interface `SmartInitializingSingleton` and in overriding method `afterSingletonsInstantiated()` execute load method.